# Deployed React App on Firebase-Hosting keeps crashing after a few days

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I had deployed my React App (which uses Firebase Auth and Firestore) on Firebase hosting. It worked fine for a few days but then suddenly started showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTOSd.png).
I think it might be due to some package conflicts, so here's the list of packages I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "@chakra-ui/modal": "^2.3.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "firebase": "^10.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

Also, here's the firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried re-building and deploying using `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` but in no vain. Even rolling back to the initial deployed version doesn't help.
Also, I've made sure that the index.html in my public is the same as the one in build